# hmmlearn decoded hidden states changes

Tags: python, machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I am using this Python library for Hidden Markov Model. https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn

```
    //use whole sequence for HMM training
    rescaled_model = GaussianHMM(n_components= 3, covariance_type="full", n_iter=2000).fit(rescaled_A)
    rescaled_hidden_states = rescaled_model.predict(rescaled_A)

//use partial sequence for HMM training
    train_len = int(len(rescaled_A) * 0.999)
    model_test = GaussianHMM(n_components= 3, covariance_type="full", n_iter=2000).fit(rescaled_A**[:train_len]**)
    hidden_states_test = model_test.predict(rescaled_A)

    print('rescaled_hidden_states: ', collections.Counter(rescaled_hidden_states))
    print('hidden_states_test: ', collections.Counter(hidden_states_test))
```

As we can see, the decoded hidden state changes b/c of the training/testing data split. The first case has 2305 hidden state 1, while the second case has 2305 hidden state 0. This changes label which makes it impossible to correctly predict next hidden state and interpret its meaning.

```
rescaled_hidden_states:  Counter({1: 2305, 2: 1537, 0: 744})
hidden_states_test:  Counter({0: 2305, 2: 1534, 1: 747})
```

Comment: does anybody notice this problem?

Comment: yes, i noticed the same problem. the only way around the prediction is to predict one by one observation, where in each additional observation you include the training window too, which can become very time-consuming. other alternative, write your own package